# What do you call a spy's code name?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call a spy's code name?

Comment: Uh, "code name".

Comment: *Handle*, perhaps? The real question is "What do spies call a spy's code name?" I suspect that the answer is *code name*.

Comment: @NigelJ Good job I wasn't drinking my cofveve. It would have gone all over my keyboard. :D

Comment: @NigelJ Why did you delete it? Let the mods do that.

Comment: You need to indicate whether you are looking for a linguistic term, or whether you are looking for something else. Also, you need to show what research you have done in order to bring your question on topic. As it stands, it is likely to be closed.

Comment: NOC, official cover, or "legend". Also, CIA have "work" names. Other than that, the answer by Nigel J is good.

Comment: I hated being the deciding vote in closing this fun question, but the necesary research has not been done, _and_ the SWR tag requires a sample sentence showing how the word is to be used. If it is edited to repair these faults, the question will be placed in the re-open queue.

Answer (score 21):

The official word for a clandestine name appears to be **cryptonym.**

> CIA **cryptonyms** are code names or code words used by the U.S. Central Intelligence Agency (CIA) to refer to projects, operations, persons, agencies, etc.
>
> Each CIA cryptonym contains a two character prefix called a digraph, which designates a geographical or functional area.[2] Certain digraphs were changed over time; for example, the digraph for the Soviet Union changed at least twice
>
> Examples from publications by former CIA personnel show that the terms "code name" and "cryptonym" can refer to the names of operations as well as to individual persons

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_cryptonym)

Comment: I found [this site](http://www.spywriter.com/robots/cia_cryptonym.html) if you want to cite it. Oh, wait a minute, that's the one you used.

Comment: The military in general (of which, arguably, the intelligence community is a subset, and which also conducts covert operations of its own) uses *callsign*.

Comment: @flith that sounds like it could be a separate answer

Comment: When you say "_The_ official word", I believe you mean "The official _CIA_ word". This answer is very specific to a particular country and agency, for how they generate `code names or code words`.

Comment: To refute the other Nigel, you might want to use the [RAF Museum website](http://www.nationalcoldwarexhibition.org/schools-colleges/national-curriculum/espionage/the-cambridge-four.aspx), where they also use the word _cryptonym_ to variously name Philby as _Stanley_, MacClean as _Homer_ , etc. While this word (cryptonym) is used by the British in this case, note that the name was assigned originally by NKVD, later absorbed into the KGB. These names are unlike the all-caps cryptonyms often used by CIA, and sometimes Mi-6, (such as the "double" NODDY in Polish UB), (continued...)

Comment: (cont.)  but closer to the usage of the CIA who assigned "work" names which were just aliases. However, it is thought that Mi-6 also used single word codes (non-caps) to identify foreign assets such as doubles and "false-flag" agents.

Comment: Cryptonym isn't quite right. That's a high-level label for the concept of using a substitute name, rather than the specific application for a person, and more specifically an intelligence officer. It's like replying to 'What do you call a place that serves quickly-prepared food?' with 'Establishment'. Technically it's correct as a 'fast-food restaurant' is a form of 'establishment', but it's not the specific term.

Answer (score 14):

**alias**

> noun
>
> 1. a false name used to conceal one's identity; an assumed name:

[from dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/alias)

Answer (score 9):

pseudonym could be used since a spy's code name is a fictitious name

Answer (score 7):

If you're in London, you can use 'monikker' (or monicker, moniker) - it means slang name, or 'name you go by' 'name you are known by' (but not  your real name). Apparently that's from an old Irish word for 'name'.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/monicker

Example:
'Usually Demery's monikker was agent 091, when he was working.'

If in America, how about 'handle' - the word for a trucker's slang name. (And apparently much earlier, according to this link).

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/handle

'Demery's handle was agent 091.'

Here are some rather posh ones 'sobriquet' 'epithet'

But for spies how about 'nom de guerre' (lit . war name in french).

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nickname

I'd use 'code word' 'spy code' 'agent code' 'agent key'.

Example:
'Demery - agent code 091 - left the building, concealing his weapon under his heavy coat.'

Comment: London but not the rest of England or the UK? How come?

Comment: Google ngram shows no signs of monikker.  Moniker/monicker appeared about 1910, and the former has nearly always been marginally more common until 1980; since then it has become overwhelming so (25:1)

Comment: @MartinBonner: Yes - and I can find no reference to "monikker" in any of the dictionaries I've looked in (though they all have the other two forms). Jelila, do you have any references that support using this as the preferred form?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am from London and know it from there but I can't speak for the rest of the UK. I know it from TV shows like The Sweeney and just from heard speech. Eg: Winstone plays Jack Regan, a Detective Inspector with the Flying Squad – or Sweeney Todd to give the organisation it’s somewhat ridiculous cockney moniker – who is waging war on London’s most violent villains. That's from a review of The Sweeney but still using that kind of language!  http://www.ign.com/articles/2012/09/11/the-sweeney-review

Comment: @psmears no I don't, I only know the word from hearing and absorbing it and monikker was my hunch on spelling - it being unusual or logically, impossible in English to have a single 'k' and a soft 'o'. (It should sound 'mon eye ker' if spelt like that. Whereas it sounds 'mon ick er'. But it's a slang word, I thought it could come from a name or be Cockney rhyming slang, I was surprised it was older and came from Ireland!

Comment: As the link you show says, *monicker* definitely isn't directly from an Old Irish word for name. It's probably from Shelta *munik*, which is possibly loosely based on Irish *ainm*. Granted *ainm* does in turn come from Old Irish, but that's jumping past anything explaining why *monicker* sounds and looks like it does.

Comment: More pertinently, as the link you show says, it's incorrect to say "but not your real name", the link says "a personal name or nickname", so a persons real name would count.

Comment: @JonHanna my experience of the use of monicker or moniker is that it refers to a different, or changed name, from the person's original name. There is more on that, and examples of usage, at this link: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moniker

Comment: Again, you link to something that proves my point. One definition says "especially when they have changed it" and *especially* in a definition entails "but not always", the other definitions say "name or nickname". A nickname may be a moniker, but a moniker would not necessarily be a nickname. A moniker would also not generally be an alias, for that matter, nor a handling code name (it's not clear which sort of code name the querent is looking for).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71582/discussion-between-jelila-and-jon-hanna).

Answer (score 3):

The definition of **[code name](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/code_name)** is *a **word** used for secrecy or convenience instead of the usual name.* e.g “‘using the code name ‘Charlie’, Dick was on the phone with the President more and more’”

Alternatively,

> **undercover name**

Examples of usage

- “It's me,” she responded. “My room in thirty minutes.” Jake's **undercover name** was Antonio Bonelli, and if he were in trouble, he would've answered as Tony.
- In the British **spy** drama *MI-5* (known as Spooks in the U.K.), what is Tom Quinn's **undercover name** at the beginning of the series? .
- Virgilio worked in tandem with another **spy** who was situated in Paris, Enrico Insabato, whose **undercover name** was 'Dante'.1

Via [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22undercover%20name%22%20spy&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD-tWitdLYAhWCVBQKHZDCDGoQ_AUIECgB&biw=1345&bih=620)

Comment: An undercover name and a code name are different things though. James Bond's code name is 007. The names he used when undercover include 'David Somerset', 'Charles Morton' and so on http://www.jamesbondwiki.com/page/James+Bond+Aliases

Comment: @PeteKirkham the Oxford Dictionary doesn't cite an example with numbers. I checked. e.g. `I don't know why the Secret Service gives out the code name, but his code name is Tumbler.’` The term is more elastic than you interpret it to be.

Comment: The code name can be anything. The point I'm making that the code name (e.g. 007) and an undercover name (e.g. 'David Somerset') are not the same thing. One is secret, the other is public. For your first quote, searching for code names in the book yields things like 'AppleJack' and 'le lion' rather than plausible aliases used when undercover https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CG7XCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT128&ots=5L3J2oRsgS&dq=Jake's%20undercover%20name%20was%20Antonio%20Bonelli%2C%20and%20if%20he%20were%20in%20trouble%2C%20he%20would've%20answered%20as%20Tony&pg=PT128#v=onepage&q=code%20name&f=false

Comment: @PeteKirkham so the best answer is "code name".